# Where to download old iphone SDKs?

Tags: iphone

Not immediately seeing where to download legacy versions of the iphone SDKs. I can get the latest 3.1.3 release and 3.2 betas off the Apple developer site, but a lot of example code I'm finding online was written for 2.0-2.2 and it is still relevant code, but I can't build them because I don't have the 2.0-2.2 SDK. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what I'm doing is using the 3.1.3 SDK, then setting the target to 2.x or 3.x depending on my needs.  I don't have XCode open but look under Project or Build menu items.

You can also set build it using the following instructions:  [iPhone Development Guide - "Specifying the Buildtime Environment"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Running_Applications/running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW1)

Comment: Project Settings, then specify the Base SDK.

Comment: Yes- after digging around a bit, I found these settings. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't help me, I have the latest 3.2 SDK from the apple site, which was the first one I ever installed.  It only lets me specify a base SDK going back to 3.0, nothing older.    How do I use the older SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

They're tough to find on the iPhone Developer section of ADC, here's a good listing of all the old SDKs download URLs.

You need to be an official iPhone developer, and login first to download these:

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html